# Conditions to apply variation of constant méthod on a Cauchy problem

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-problem

I try to solve the following Cauchy Problem on the interval $[0,T[$ for a $T>0$:

$
\left\{\begin{matrix}y'(t) = -\frac{4}{t} y(t)
\\ y(0)=0
\end{matrix}\right.
$

What I did:

I found the variation of constant method which gives the unique solution 
 $e^{\int_{0}^{t}\frac{-4}{s}ds}y(0)=0$  . But I am not convinced that $t \rightarrow \frac{-4}{t}$ is continuous on [0,T] to ensure that the integral have a meaning.

Many thanks if you can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

note that $ -\int_{0}^{t}\frac{4}{s}ds=\int_{t}^{0}\frac{4}{s}ds=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0}(4\text{log}(x))-4\text{log}(t)$, where the limit is $-\infty$. Now if some $f \rightarrow -\infty$ , what happens to $e^{f}$ ?

Comment: $e^f$ vanishes to 0 in that case.

Comment: My question boils down to the following:
Can we use the variation of constant if a(s)  continuous on $]0,t[$ without being defined on $0$

Comment: you can, because in that very case, you can integrate $a(s)$ if you accept to have $\pm \infty$ as possible values.